# How to fix downward incompatibility of VBA Macro for getting Excel data in MS-Word 2007?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have written a VBA Macro in MS-Word to get data from some Excel cells. It starts with this:

```
Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
```

It works alright in MS-Word 2010. But in MS-Word 2007 the following error occurs when the Macro is run:

```
Compile error: Can't find project or library
```

and the line of Macro quoted above is highlighted.

In my Word 2007, under the macro window, when I choose Tools->Reference, I found Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library is ticked, but another box "MISSING: Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library" is also ticked. So it seems the code is only valid under the latter library. How should I change the code so that it can work under Word 2007, which uses 12.0 Object Library instead? Thanks!

Comment: Try declaring `objExcel` as an `Object` and using `Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`.

Comment: @stribizhev, it's called late binding ;)

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for the link, it solved my problem. I didn't know that the 12.0 Object Library was used as early as Office 2000.

Comment: @LaBird I believe that was a typo. 12.0 is Office 2007. 11.0 is Office 2003. It does not matter which version is which, the point was to use late binding.